# Is trere a simplier way to have concurrentmap with locks?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a requireement to have locks in some function per entity ID.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Long, Lock> idLocks = Maps.newConcurrentMap();

public void doSmth(Long id){
    ReentrantLock newLock = new ReentrantLock();
    Lock lock = prLocks.putIfAbsent( id, newLock ); //returns null for first run for this id
    if (null == lock) { //have to do null checking 
        lock = newLock;
    }
    if (lock.tryLock()){
        try {
        //some code here
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to run `Lock lock = returnExistingOrPutAndReturnNew( id, newLock );` to get rid of null checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such method in ConcurrentMap, but you can use [guava LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html):

```
private final LoadingCache<Long, Lock> idLocks = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .build(
             new CacheLoader<Long, Lock>() {
                   public Lock load(Long id) throws AnyException {
                       return new ReentrantLock();
                   }
             });

public void doSmth(Long id){
     Lock lock = prLocks.get(id); //always return not-null Lock
     if (lock.tryLock()){
          try {
             //some code here
          } finally {
             lock.unlock();
          }
     }
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

In java 8 you can use [Map#computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
public void doSmth(Long id){
    Lock lock = prLocks.computeIfAbsent(id, key -> new ReentrantLock());
    if (lock.tryLock()){
        try {
            //some code here
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems yes http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html